# vectorization: change values of multiple columns on condition

Tags: r

I want to change the multiple column values base cell condition in a vectorization way. I know how to change value one column by one  column but how to change more than two column at the same time. For example, if col1 or col2 <3, we want to set these cell to 99.

```
     col1<-seq(1,5)
     col2<-(1:5)
     col3<-10:14
     df<-data.frame(col1,col2,col3)

     df[df[,1:2]<5]<-99 ##wrong, but it works for a single column

     ifelse(df[,1:2]<5,99,??) # i dont know how to set the value to the original values here

# works for single column
df[df$col1<5,1]<-99
df[df$col2<5,2]<-99

> df
  col1 col2 col3
1   99   99   10
2   99   99   11
3   99   99   12
4   99   99   13
5    5    5   14
```

Comment: or `df[which(df[1:2]<5, arr.ind = TRUE)] <- 999`

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi, it is a good name,lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are getting a `matrix` of logical elements i.e. `TRUE/FALSE` based on two columns.  So, if we need to subset the elements of the two columns, select only those columns to subset the elements and assign it to 999

```
df[1:2][df[1:2] < 5] <- 999
```

---

This can be made clear if we split up the code and check the individual components i.e.

1) A matrix of logical elements

```
 df[1:2] < 5
 #      col1  col2
 #[1,]  TRUE  TRUE
 #[2,]  TRUE  TRUE
 #[3,]  TRUE  TRUE
 #[4,]  TRUE  TRUE
 #[5,] FALSE FALSE
```

2) Select the columns of interest to subset those satisfy the condition in the logical matrix

```
 df[1:2][df[1:2] < 5]
 #[1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

Imagine if we are applying this on the whole dataset.  Then, the dimension/length are not the same.  In some cases, it may even work out by recyling if the number of columns in the original dataset is a multiple of the logical matrix columns (so beware of that possibility)

3) Assign the values to 999

---

Using `ifelse` can be done on `vector`s.  So loop through the columns and then do the assignment

```
df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], function(x) ifelse(x < 5, 999, x))
```

Or with `replace`

```
df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], function(x) replace(x, x < 5, 999))
```

Comment: why are the results of df[1:2][df[1:2] < 5] not in a dataframe format?

Comment: @alphabetagamma  Updated the `ifelse` option.  We are extracting values from data.frame and it is no longer a data.frame but only a vector of values.  But during the assignment, it will match those index and replace it in the original dataset